# What's contained in 'kernel mode' in virtual address space of a process?

Tags: operating-systems

I'm reading through [Mickens' OS notes](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/%7Ecs161/), and I came across the following depiction of a virtual address space. [image]

I conceptually understand "user mode" of a process' virtual address space. It contains program instructions, stack, heap, static data, etc.

But what about 'kernel mode'? I always thought of kernel instructions as elsewhere... I thought of kernel as a separate process. And when a system call happens that kernel process gets loaded and a handler gets executed.

- Is this incorrect? Part of the kernel is co-located with the process? Which part?

Comment: I find it weird to label sections of address space as "mode"s.  These separate [spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) have different accessibility by processor privilege level (aka [CPU mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_modes)) but spaces themselves are not modes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And when a system call happens that kernel process gets loaded and a handler gets executed.

This would be extremely slow as a process context switch would be required to make a kernel call and another one when the kernel call returns. Please consider that even a simple operation like printing "Hello World" to the screen using `printf()` in C requires at least one (quite often more than one) kernel call.

To speed things up, the kernel is mapped into the virtual address space of every process. A kernel call is basically just a jump to a function in the kernel address space, which is almost as fast as calling a normal function in your code; this way no context switch is required at all.

It is a bit slower as a normal function call because the kernel code runs on a different privilege level than the user space code and when calling a kernel function a privilege level increase has to take place (hence the function is called using the `SYSCALL` instructions instead of the `CALL` instruction on x86 CPUs). Alternatively a software interrupt can be used for that purpose but interrupt handling is much slower, so modern systems don't use interrupts anymore for this purpose unless the CPU has nothing else available. Please see [typical implementations on system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call#Typical_implementations) for details.

So the kernel is similar to a dynamic shared library that is implicitly loaded for all applications and available in address space, with the exception, that it has a global state across all applications. The downside is that less virtual address space is available for user space processes. This is one reason why 64 bit CPUs make sense as with 64 bit pointers, the virtual address space is enormous and losing a bit for the kernel is totally irrelevant in that case.

Another advantage is that the kernel can also easily access the memory of user space code that made the call as that memory is within the same virtual address space of the code that handles the system call. When you perform a kernel call that requires the kernel to access user space memory, this memory doesn't have to be copied between processes or use some implicit shared memory mechanism, instead the call just passes a pointer along and the kernel directly reads the data from the address the pointer references.

Comment: For 32 bit systems where you need all 4GiByte of address space for user processes, there used to be a Linux kernel patch that moves the kernel into a separate address space. I'm pretty sure there are benchmarks that compare the standard 3:1 address space split with the so-called 4:4 split. That would tell you *exactly* what the performance impact is, using the exact same benchmark on the exact same OS on the exact same hardware.

Comment: @JörgWMittag The patch causes a slowdown anywhere between 0% and 30% for real world applications (possibly worse for certain kind of benchmarks) according to this mailing list post: https://lwn.net/Articles/39283/

Comment: @Mecki and now we pay that penalty anyway because of Meltdown/Spectre mitigations (KPTI).

Comment: @user253751 But only because Intel botched up their caching (others did as well but Intel the most). If they had not skipped cache clean up as they deemed it's waste of time, none of these problems would even exist. There exists at least two strategies for that (cache rollback and shadow caching) and neither one would has any influence on performance at all. It would just have require additional cache space and some more transistors to manage it.